# Splitting a sequence into fixed width

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I have a file like this which is a two-column tab-separated file.

```
CTGCAGTTTCCCCAAATGTGGGAAACTTGACTGTATAATTTGTGGCAGTGGTA   a1
GATTTCCCCAAATGTGGGAAACTCACTCGGCAGGCGTTGATA  a2
```

I want to get an output like this:

```
>a1
CTGCAGTTTCCCCAAATGTG
GGAAACTTGACTGTATAATT
TGTGGCAGTGGTA
>a2
GATTTCCCCAAATGTGGGAA
ACTCACTCGGCAGGCGTTGA
TA
```

I was trying to use the fold command inside [awk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK). Is it possible to use another command within `awk`?

Also, the width of each line I want is 15, so I tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
awk -F "\t" '{a=$(fold -w 50 $1);print a,$2}' file.txt
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Your example output is neither two column nor is it clear where the TAB would be.

Comment: I changed it. My input file is 2 column tab separated. I never said out put to be a 2 column. Sorry if it caused a confusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `python test.py < input` and `test.py`:

```
import sys
for i in sys.stdin:
     s, ident = i.rstrip().split()
     print '>{0}'.format(ident)
     while s:
          print s[:15]
          s = s[15:]
```

Comment: Hi Anthon
Anything in awk?? I just want to use another command within awk. Thanks for the solution

Comment: @user3138373 Sorry, I don't think my `awk` skills will get you anything useful, nor am I sure you can call other commands from `awk`.

Answer (score 5):

Here are a couple of ways:

1. Perl

   ```
   perl -ane '$F[0]=~s/.{15}/$&\n/g; print ">$F[1]\n$F[0]\n"' file
   ```
2. awk

   ```
   awk '{i=0; printf ">%s\n",$2;
          while(i<=length($1)){
               printf "%s\n", substr($1,i,15);i+=15
           }}' file
   ```

If you really want to use `fold` within awk, you could do

```
awk '{printf ">%s\n",$2; system("echo " $1 "| fold -w 15 ") }' file
```

Your attempt failed because `$()` is a shell thing, not an `awk` thing. To run system commands from within `awk`, you need to use `system()`. Then, in order to pass the *value* of `$1` (the sequence) and not the actual string `$1` to the shell (if you do, the shell will try and evaluate it and it will return a blank since `$1` is not set), you need to exclude the `$1` from the quotes.

So, in this example, I am using

```
               |-------------------------> closing quotes for the 1st part
               |                    |----> closing quotes for the 2nd part
               v                    v   
system( " echo "  $1  " | fold -w 15")
        - ----    --- - ------------
        |  |       |  |       |----------> the 2nd part
        |  |       |  |------------------> opening quotes for the 2nd part       
        |  |       |---------------------> The awk variable, `$1`, 
        |  |                               outside the quotes.         
        |  |-----------------------------> The 1st part       
        |--------------------------------> opening quotes for the 1st part
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you explain the answer with fold command??

Comment: @user3138373 `$()` is a shell construct, not `awk`. To call a system command with `awk`, you use `system()`. The quoting is funky to protect `$1` from being expanded by the shell.

Comment: Thanks terdon. Also I tried removing double quotes ; something like this and it gave me error so what are those quotes doing
awk '{printf ">%s\n",$2; system(echo "$1" | fold -w 15 ) }'file.txt

Comment: @user3138373 see updated answer, is that clearer?

Comment: It's a little unclear; it means echo was in double quotes and "|fold -w 15" in double quotes?? I though $1 is in double quotes. Looking more carefully

Comment: @user3138373 look at the syntax highlighting. There are two quoted strings there and one unquoted one: `" echo "` and `" | fold -w 15"` are quoted because they need to be passed directly to the shell launched by `system()` but `$1` is not quoted since that is an awk variable and needs to be evaluated by `awk`, and its _contents_ passed to the shell.

Comment: awesome terdon. I got it now. Also I remember once I used backslash character in shell to escape $1, something like this \$1. Is it ok to do that. Haven't tried though. I will look at that code what I was doing there

Comment: @user3138373 no, `\$1` makes no sense in this context. That would just give an error. `\\$1` would pass the literal string `$1` to the shell, so `system("echo \\$1")` would print `$1`. The double escape is needed because you need to escape the `\ ` from awk itself. Also, if this or any other answer solved your issue, please accept it so the question can be marked as solved.

Comment: Note that depending on external commands (a shell instance and the fold process) is neither necessary nor performant; this external shell pipeline is called for **each** input data line once.

Comment: @Janis yes, I wouldn't use a system call for this. That's why I posted the other two approaches. The OP [wanted to do this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189333/splitting-a-sequence-into-fixed-width/189336?noredirect=1#comment316135_189335) by launching another program within awk though, so I provided a way.

Comment: terdon, yes, but since the OP seems to have been focussing on that version I wanted to let him and readers know about the drawbacks.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{ print ">"$2 ; while (length($1)) { print substr($1,1,15) ; $1=substr($1,16) } }'
```

Comment: Nice, +1. I recommend using `printf` though since `print ">",$2` will add a space between the `>` and `$2`.

Comment: terdon, removing the comma in `print` serves as well to achieve that.